# xsd restrict gYear between 1900 and this year?

Tags: xml, date, xsd, restriction

I am new to XML and wanna start with a simple movieDB. so far i got his:

```
<xs:element name="release">
       <xs:simpleType>
          <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
             <xs:minInclusive value="1900"/>
             <xs:maxInclusive value="2016"/>
          </xs:restriction>
       </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```

how would it be with the simpleType of gYear?

Answer (score 1):

### XSD 1.0

Not possible.  Must test out-of-band wrt XSD.

### XSD 1.1

Possible using `xs:assertion` and XPath 2.0 `current-date()` function:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning"
           vc:minVersion="1.1">
  <xs:element name="release">
    <xs:simpleType>
      <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
        <xs:minInclusive value="1900"/>
        <xs:assertion test="$value le year-from-date(current-date())"/>
      </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```